# jupyter notebook in Mac OSX Sierra Terminal Not Working

Tags: macos, terminal, jupyter-notebook

Instead of seeing a browser window and tab open with a jupyter notebook, I receive this: error: "http://localhost:8888/tree?token=149433459d0b8141744ba7b6b7e6f51afbba2e0c15c1d5c7" doesn’t understand the “open location” message. (-1708)
If I pick through the code and copy the correct token, I can use it in the password window to gain access. Is there a reason I can't use a Terminal command to open a jupyter notebook?

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe another process is using that port? Also, might be an issue if you have multiple pythons installed. Try uninstalling then installing Jupyter again. I recommend using [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create isolated python environments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2438 for more information. The comments on the bug indicate that adding

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = u'chrome'
```

to ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py will fix the problem, although it didn't work for me.